# CRUD regions, zones in Openstack Swift with Python

Tags: python, openstack-swift

I setup successfully a test Openstack Swift environment followed by this [SAIO - Swift All In One](http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/development_saio.html) page. And also installed [python-swiftclient](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-swiftclient) package to manage data on Swift. But both of `swift` command and `swiftclient` package only support me to manage Account, Container and Object data.

So I wonder is there any ways help me execute CRUD command for regions, zones, hard disks...with commands or Python?

Answer (score 0):

Probably you are looking for "swift-ring-builder" command:

http://docs.openstack.org/developer/swift/admin_guide.html